# Database design for a chat app

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm trying to create a web chat app using AJAX, PHP and mySQL. I'm having trouble with the database structure.. Here's what I've thought :

A users table: Contains basic user's info

A Chat table: Contains basic columns like 'to', 'from' 'timestamp' etc..

The problem:

I think that this will get pretty messy very quickly since lots of users will be querying the same table. Not to mention some security issues. I want to create a separate table for each conversation. Is this a good idea? What would be your preferred structure?

Comment: A separate table for each conversation would, in my view, be more messy and harder to administer. Any particular reason for not going for the higher performance of websockets?

Comment: "_I want to create a separate table for each conversation. Is this a good idea?_" No, please no. Use one table. It will be far messier and not of correct DB structure if there is a table per convo.

Comment: @Matt So, you're telling me that big companies use 1 table for all their conversations ? Just curious ?

Comment: Just think of it like this. With your idea, If you have two users -> one table is enough, but for 4 users you end up with at least 24 tables (not counting if they also have group conversations). So imagine how many tables you would need for 100 users ....

Comment: @candh Big companies wouldn't be having one server, much less one table... if chat is any major deal in their line of business. And they'll likely have something rather more robust for the back-end, running on servers that are optimized for and dedicated to the application. That said, if you get a lot of volume, better keep the chat app off your main server, however you may do the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate table for each conversation would be very messy indeed. A single table would get huge and degrade performance with sufficient volume and accumulation.

If you don't need to store each line of conversation in perpetuity in the database, you can simply purge the conversation from the chat lines table once it's over. You'd only need to keep it there if you wanted to search lines in past conversations. (Use other approaches for keeping chat statistics etc.)

You could archive a concatenated/serialized version of the conversation, ie. the whole lot in one chunk, into a file in the filesystem, or into a separate table with the relevant metadata (users, length, duration etc.). Then simply reload it, whenever an old conversation becomes active again.

If you do want to distribute your per-table load, you could e.g. track typical user connections and then generate an adequate amount of group-dedicated tables, or use any other user aggregation algorithm that works. But if you do purge the chat lines table periodically, it'll take a huge volume of usage before database performance will become an issue.